# Probability an abstract lakes of size $6\times 4$ units in size will become unpassable due to the positions of 5 random holes

Tags: probability, computer-science

There is a rectangular lake that people need to cross to get from village $A$ to village $B$.

This is a rather abstract lake with size $6\times 4$. Every winter it freezes over and will always have $5$ holes. These are not located at point $A (1,1)$ or point $B(6,4)$ and cannot stack on top one another, i.e. if hole 1 is at $(1,2)$ then hole 2 cannot be on the same location $(1,2)$.

What is the probability that the holes will form a complete blockage so the lake cannot be crossed from $A$ to $B$.

Examples:

I will write Entrance/Exit as `e`, ice as `x` and hole as `o`.

Example 1:

```
e x x o x x    
x x x o x x    
x x x o x x    
x x x o o e
```

this lake is unpassable.

Example 2:

```
e x x x x x
o o o o x x
x x o x x x
x x x x x e
```

this lake is passable.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)")

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Finally, notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Can you move diagonally? Or can you move vertically or horizontally only? Say from (1,1) to (2,2) while (1,2) and (2,1) are blocked.